# Scanner Motorola 9090 not reading barcode type 128B

Tags: .net, symbols

I have a hand held scanner that is not picking up bar-codes of type `128B`. I'm using `.net 2008 c#` to run the application, just a simple scan, I am using `symbol.barcode` as a reference.

Is there any suggestions? It works fine for `bar-code type 39` but cant seem to pick up `128B` at all.

Comment: Do you know the scanner type in the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In datawedge do you have the 128B symbology enabled?

Comment: I worked in the hand-held industry for a while and have done some dev work on Windows Mobile. If this isn't the answer let me know and I will try and help further

Comment: I have been speaking with Motorola and the scanner 9090 does not support 128B . so will have to look at a different device which my colleague is looking into. Thanks for your help, code blend

Comment: Ah, I think I was on the right tracks then =)

Answer (score 0):

Scanner 9090 
does not support barcode type 128B